# Elements of even order in a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite group with the property that every non-identity element has even order, what could be said about $G$? For example the most trivial property might be that $G$ is a group of even order. I was wondering if more could be said about the structure of $G$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition holds if and only if $G$ is a $2$-group; that is, if the order of $G$ is a power of $2$.

To see this, note that [Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) implies that $|G|$ cannot be divisible by an odd prime.